# Online code usage search in emacs

Tags: programming, github

I am pretty sure I have seen some service, with an emacs plugin, that does something like the following: whenever you're programming and type a function name it'll show example usages of the function call from github projects.

This can give you an idea on how functions are used in practical ways, outside the simplified and contrived examples usually found in documentation.

Does anyone know what I am talking about?

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of https://github.com/arthurnn/howdoi-emacs (which searches StackOverflow)?

Comment: Nope... it was something else...